# Как сделать, чтобы при открытии всплывающего окна фоновая картинка уже была загружена?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть  [страница со всплывающим окном](http://lpsystem.ru/tree.html). Там фоновое изображение загружается только при открытии окна. Как можно сделать, чтобы при открытии окна изображение уже было загружено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть ещё  проще решение, сразу после загрузки показать на один такт скрытые элементы (пользователь ничего не увидит):

ко всем элементам типа #dim, приделайте css класс "dim"; и добавьте  эту функцию в скрипт

```
$(function(){
  var $dim=$('.dim:not(:visible)');
  $dim.show();
  setTimeout(function(){$dim.hide()},0);
});
```

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо. Только что эта функция делает?

Comment: то что я сказал, показывает и тут-же прячет все скрытые элементы класса dim.

Answer (score 2):

"открыть" модальное окно, но с "display:none", чтобы не было видно. Потом дождаться события "onLoad" для картинки и показать модальное окно.

Comment: В таком случае на медленном интернете окно будет открываться долго, и пользователь не поймёт, что к чему.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, тогда какой-нибудь ajax-лоадер повешай, чтобы крутился пока все там грузится

Comment: То есть подругому вообще никак? Чтобы она загрузилась до открытия окна

Comment: ну вот что можно сделать...

    $(function(){$('<img>,{width:0,heigh:0,position: absolute,left: -10000;}').appendTo('<body>').load(function(){$(this).remove()}).attr('src',"http://lpsystem.ru/img/aboutwindow.png");});

Comment: А это что за код? Куда его поставить нужно?

Comment: это javasript, прелоадит картинку, можно поставить в тэге <script> на вашей странице (я видел в хедере один) если картинок много, то надо написать функцию.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, картинок несколько.

Answer (score -1):

тебе нужно оптимизировать этот бекграунд. картинка слишком много весит и первый раз браузер долго ее кеширует

Comment: Тоесть так всё нормально? Она там грузится до открытия окна?

Comment: не грузит браузер бэкрграунды скрытых элементов, до того как их покажет.

Comment: @eicto, а я это и имел ввиду